# React-leaflet i cant use styled components in divicon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I need to use styled component for leaflet marker I try the code below but it returns `[object Object]` as marker icon. How can i solve this? I tried lots of things but i cant use components for react-leaflet marker

```
                                        const icon = L.divIcon({
                                        iconAnchor: [10, 10],
                                        html: <StyledDiv
                                        class= {`markerWithId ${
                                          item.last_state
                                            ? "MarkerWithId"
                                            : "MarkerWithId"
                                        }`}
                                        ><p 
                                        id="${item.id}"
                                        >${item.order_device}</p></StyledDiv>,
                                    });
```

Comment: You cannot use a react component for html attribute of `L.divIcon`. It expects only html not jsx

Comment: But i need to use a react component. Can't i get rendered html of react component for there?

Comment: I use `import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"` to render jsx to static html. Note that this works with static icons and so on.